# AngularJS ag-grid get columns width after resize

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ag-grid

In AngularJS ag-grid, how can I get new columns width after resizing ?

Here is part of grid configuration :

```
            $scope.gridOptions = {
                enableColResize: true                   
            };
```

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
gridOptions.columnApi.getColumnState();
```

returns informations about columns : https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-api/index.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.resizeGrid-function(grid) { 
  setTimeout(function() { 
  grid.$gridServices?.DomUtilityService.RebuildGrid(grid.$gridScope, grid.ngGrid);
  }, 100);
}
```

To fix the shrinkage issue of aggrid in angular js.

Use above function to fix the issue and just pass your grid in this function.

This solution only works for angular js not for angular.